# List Box: Display one list, return item from adjacent column in table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, list

We have a spreadsheet we fill in with billing info then upload to a host via FTP. The first column requires the customer account NUMBER. What I want to do is provide a dropdown list of Customer NAMES A-Z.(I have a 2-column table of names and numbers). When they choose a name I want to put the Customer number in the cell and not the name.

Drop down:Aname Bname Cname. when selected return and populate cell with account number 111111,222222,333333.
I can do this easy enough using vlookup, but that requires an extra column. I need to get double-duty out of that first column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

When a customer name is selected, the following macro immediately replaces the name with the customer number from the lookup table in columns D and E. The dropdown retains the list of customers. In the screenshot, Customer C had been selected first and the macro replaced the name with the number. Now the dropdown can still be used to select a different customer.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim LookupTable As Range
Set LookupTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:E100")
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, LookupTable, 2, False)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Right-click the sheet tab, select "View code" and paste the code into the code window. Adjust references to suit your workbook.

Remember to save the file as a macro-enabled workbook.